# How to read multiple integers from a single line?

Tags: c, input

Input is some integers separeted by spaces in one line, like this:

```
   enter numbers: 12 41 2
```

program should get each integers and show the sum:

```
   sum: 55
```

how can i do that?

edit:I tried this but it is unable to detect enter key. It should stop and show sum when enter is pressed.

```
printf("\nEnter numbers: ");
int sum =0;
int temp;
while( scanf("%d",&temp))
{
    sum+=temp;

}
printf("Sum: %d",sum);
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  One thing worth investigating is the `strtok` function.

Comment: Another interesting tool is the `scanf` family of functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("\nEnter numbers: ");
    int sum =0, temp;
    char ch;
    while(2 == scanf("%d%c", &temp, &ch)){
        sum+=temp;
        if(ch == '\n')
            break;
        else if(ch != ' '){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note : There is a need to enter a new line following the last number in this version.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char line[128], *p=line;
    int sum = 0, len, n;

    printf("enter numbers: ");
    scanf("%127[^\n]", line);
    while (sscanf(p, "%d%n", &n, &len)==1){
        sum += n;
        p += len;
    }
    printf("sum: %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replacing the `scanf` line with `fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)` would be much clearer...

Comment: +1 for the `%n` trick.  ( I agree a `fgets()` would be cleaner)

Comment: BLuepixy is the master of answering questions with obfuscated code samples that actually work :)

Comment: thanks but it does not wait user to give input, just gives this:"enter numbers: sum: 0"

Comment: @user3525373 `scanf("%127[^\n]", line);` This will wait for user input. I think that there is a problem with something else. For example, enter and already entered.

Comment: Repeat start time of the keyboard is probably short.